# Can "stagnate" be used as a transitive verb?

Tags: word-usage, intransitive-verbs

I know that some verbs can be used either transitively or intransitively.  Is it acceptable to use a verb transitively that is generally not used that way? As in:

"I can't continue to stagnate myself with fear of failure."

research so far:

“Stagnate.” Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stagnate. Accessed 12 Sep. 2023.

Nordquist, Richard. "What Is an Intransitive Verb?" ThoughtCo, Jan. 29, 2020, thoughtco.com/intransitive-verb-term-1691185.

Warriner, John E. *Warriner's English Grammar and Composition.* Liberty ed. (Orlando: Harcourt Brace Jovanovich, 1986) 13-14.

Comment: What do you mean "is it acceptable?"?  If your editor has a specific dictionary, and it says "intransitive (only)" they probably will complain, and it'll look odd to people who're used to it being intransitive, but is that OK for you? What are your criteria? What did your research tell you?

Comment: Maybe but the myself kills it, imo.

Comment: Like @Lambie I find the reflexive pronoun more objectionable than the transitive use of the verb.  Myself, I'd avoid both problems entirely and write  *I can't continue to stagnate for fear of failure.*

Comment: I've certainly *spoken*, *read*, and *heard* it used in this manner (and, after seeing @DjinTonic's [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/612514/366), I'm not surprised I have)

Comment: Using the verb **stagnate** transitively nowadays would sound strange to a very large majority of native speakers. It's like using the verb **cease** transitively with a direct object.

Answer (score 12):

> **Stagnate** (v.)
>
> *Transitive*. To cause to be or become stagnant.
>
> **1693** Whence gushed out an Inundation of Water, that is here stagnated, and become a filthy Lake. J. Edwards, *Discourse concerning
> Old & New-Testament* vol. I. iv. 134
>
> **1842** The power which these bodies have of stopping the transmission of heat depends on the air which is stagnated in their
> vacuities. J. C. Loudon, *Suburban Horticulturist* 68
>
> *Transferred and figurative.*
>
> **1906** There is a tendency for age to stagnate a man's initiative, invention and energy.
> *Daily Chronicle* 18 October 4/7
> [OED]

I would say that the transitive use is certainly uncommon and might raise the eyebrows of today's readers.<sup>*</sup> *The New Oxford American Dictionary* (First edition) does not show it as transitive. I started to write that I couldn't find it sanctioned in any of my collegiate-size dictionaries (e.g. Collins), but then checked one more and found:

> *vt.* To make stagnant
> [*Webster's New World Dictionary*, Third College Edition (1988)]

And in a comment below, Warren adds [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stagnate):

> *verb (used with object)*, stag·nat·ed, stag·nat·ing.
>
> To make stagnant.
>
> Overtime has expressed interest in this age group of athletes in the
> past, however the strict rules on how the publisher could work with
> this cohort of players aged 16 to 22 **stagnated** that interest.
> ‘Talent-first company’: How Overtime is positioning itself as a
> content partner for college athletes’ NIL deals | Kayleigh Barber |
> August 10, 2021 | Digiday

---

Found with Google Books:

> All closed corners **stagnate** the air, even where the building forms
> but three sides of a square, unless the wings are so short that they
> can hardly be called wings.
> [Florence Nightingale; *Notes on
> Hospitals*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Notes_on_Hospitals/53MnBgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to%20stagnate%20the%22&pg=PA21&printsec=frontcover) (1859)

> Anything which tends to **stagnate** growth hurts the dairy industry,
> and I think his plan would tend to **stagnate** the acceptance of new
> inventions, and new technology, and increase rather than decrease unit
> costs of production.
> [Dr. Roland Bartlett; *Hearings Before the Committee on
> Agriculture*, U.S. House, Committee on Agriculture](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hearings_Before_the_Committee_on_Agricul/y9lGAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to%20stagnate%20the%22&pg=RA6-PA21&printsec=frontcover) (1957)

> Haunting and alarming worldwide threats have amputated global attention from the issue of near-Earth space junk. From obvious concerns on the ground, to imperceptible despair above
> the atmosphere in the form of orbital debris, the consequences could
> **stagnate** the entire world and even cast it indefinitely back into the pale past. For some, this might sound like a good science-fiction movie, but the breaking up of space debris holds practical significant. People on the ground, even if they don't acknowledge it, are in constant dependence on the evolution of events about their heads.
> [Ion Storland; *Extracting the Future from The
> Present*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Extracting_The_Future_from_The_Present/95cLEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22could%20stagnate%20the%22&pg=PA27&printsec=frontcover) (2020)

---

<sup>*</sup>One eyebrow per reader.

Comment: It seems I may have had tunnel vision when looking around the internet for my answer.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm surprised that it was ever correct; it certainly _sounds_ wrong to this native speaker.

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stagnate shows the words being used transitively in an example, too

Comment: @warren Thank you--added.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. The formal answer is "No." It's not grammatical.

You could say, "I refuse to become stagnant..." Or "I refuse to let myself stagnate through indecision."

But if, for example, you're using the suggested wording as dialogue in fiction, then anything goes, because people don't always speak grammatically.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some citation or reasoning for your claim that this is not grammatical.

Comment: ... which would be difficult, as OED licenses the transitive usage, with a recent example. A rare usage though, doubtless.